# tesseract returns empty string when image is passed. i have cropped the text from a larger image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

i am working on data which contain text on cable which is attached to board , my objective is extract text from cable , here i have the cropped image [image cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJk61.jpg)  . then I de-skew it and then pass it to  tesseract [de-skewed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6oeq.jpg). i get the following output **'QW -CIRE2-9'** which is completely irrelevant. could someone please help me resolve this. i have tried other pre processing steps such dilation and shareholding but still it is completely gibberish

Comment: Tesseract does not perform well when the text is skewed, you would need to align it horizontally

Comment: Your input image is highly distorted, rendering the classifier pretty much unreliable. You need to pre-process the input to achieve a better result. Try to unwarp the perspective first and then threshold it to obtain a cleaner binary image before applying morphology.

Comment: You need to dewarp image/text line.